# How do I check to see if my SQLDB service instance has been hibernated or not (Bluemix)

Tags: ibm-cloud

How do I check to see if my SQLDB service instance has been hibernated or not, is there an easy way to check?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what you mean by "hibernated" but if your service is bound to the application and the application starts successfully, then your service is in good shape.  You can also view the status of all Bluemix services by checking the site below:

https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/support/#status

If this does not address your question, please provide more detail and I'll try to assist.